# Tomcat5 startup - denied permission for catalina.out

Tags: tomcat, osx-lion, macports

After a system upgrade i am no longer able to start my *tomcat5* server. Executing the *startup.sh* results in following message:

```
imac:bin mmm$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat_bak
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat_bak
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat_bak/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat_bak/bin/bootstrap.jar
touch: /Library/Tomcat_bak/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
/Library/Tomcat_bak/bin/catalina.sh: line 294: /Library/Tomcat_bak/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

The user- and rightsettings are the same as before the upgrade:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 macports  admin   1,1K 29 Mär  2010 startup.sh
```

What i've done:
I upgraded my iMac *Snow Leopard* to *Lion*. This caused some errors for e.g *python*, so i updated macports and reinstalled the ports i needed (according to the instructions on the macPorts page. I have not reinstalled any tomcat port manually).

Regards
mmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a user/group problem after the os upgrade. I reinstalled tomcat without using macports and now it works.